# ORA-00904 invalid identifier while update table using CASE statement

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, ora-00904

I create a stored procedure in which I update a table using a `CASE` statement. **user_in** is the input parameter of the stored procedure.

Here is the `UPDATE` statement:

```
update tbl
set col1 = CASE WHEN (user_in = txt.col3) THEN 'ABC'
                ELSE 'XYZ'
           END
where col2 = v_col2;
```

Where `user_in` and `v_col2` are input parameters, `txt` is the another table where we are matching the value of `col3` to `user_in` value. If they match, then set `col1` of `tbl` to `ABC`, otherwise set it to `XYZ`.

While executing the stored procedure, I get an error:

> ORA-00904 invalid identifier

How to resolve this issue so that i can easily update the table and the stored procedure will compile successfully. Thanks

Comment: I think you need to join table txt with tbl in the update statement. Try to search Merge statement in Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create it in such a way :

```
create or replace procedure pr_upd_tbl( v_col2 int, user_in int ) is
begin
update tbl t
   set col1 = CASE
                WHEN (user_in = ( select col3 from txt x where x.id = t.id ) ) THEN
                 'ABC'
                ELSE
                 'XYZ'
              END
 where col2 = v_col2;
end;
```